# get graphel barchart label value onlick in javascript

Tags: raphael, graphael

I am trying to get the value of the clicked text from a barchart built with graphael library. I am using a function to create the labels for the barchart and here is the text part:

```
l= a.text(x, y, labels[i]).attr({ font: "20px Helvetica" , cursor: "pointer" }).click(function () {
 $document.getElementByTagName('tspan').value;
```

});

Comment: Why not use Raphaels 'this' element, its not clear without more code if yours is correct. I would put a test example that runs on a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the target property from the mouseEvent.

```
$(event.target).text();
```